# VideoFrameProcessor's VideoFrameYUV data corrupted in 4:3 mode

Tags: dji-sdk

This is using a Phantom 4 Pro.

We have implemented a `VideoFrameProcessor` in our Swift app and register it with the `DJIVideoPreviewer`. This all seems to work great when we are in `DJICameraPhotoAspectRatio.ratio16_9`. The image shows up in the frame processor as 1280x720, and we can decode the data just fine into a UIImage.

However, if we switch to `DJICameraPhotoAspectRatio.ratio4_3`, then we get an image reported to be of size 960x720 and when we decode the data into an UIImage it has artifacts and green barring.

Is there a way to get proper images from the frame processor in 4:3 mode?

Here is 16:9, looks perfect.

[image: 16:9]

Here is 4:3, has artifacts and green barring.

[image: 4:3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to get hardware encoding working. That solved the issue. At some point in your code base you need to set a global function so DJI can load prebuilt I-frames for the h264 stream. It is not documented anywhere. Hope this helps someone else.

`g_loadPrebuildIframeOverrideFunc = loadPrebuildIframePrivate`

You can view the list of supported I frames [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/DJIWidget/blob/master/DJIWidget/VideoService/DJIVTH264DecoderIFrameData.m)

You can see my GitHub comment [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/issues/315#issuecomment-575428500)